# How to use already installed ghc with stack inside nix-shell?

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack, nix, nix-shell

I have already installed `ghc` using `stack` build tool. It compiles my project. But when I enter `nix-shell` inside project directory and want to compile my project from `nix-shell` I see error like this:

```
No compiler found, expected minor version match with ghc-8.0.2
```

This can be fixed by running `stack setup` command. But I worry that this will install `ghc` once more time consuming more space on my machine and etc. Is there a way to use already installed `ghc` for `nix-shell` without running `stack setup` command?

Comment: I know nothing about `nix`, but AFAIK running `stack setup` won't redownload a version of GHC if that version was already downloaded somewhere on your computer. Stack tries as much as possible to share downloads between projects.

Comment: These days stack wants to use its own ghc unless `--system-ghc` is passed or `system-ghc: true` is specified in config.yaml / stack.yaml.  So, I recommend putting `system-ghc: true` in `config.yaml`.

Comment: @mgsloan Thanks for your advice! Probably, this is the solution. Also considering adding `ghc` to `PATH`.

Comment: Is stack meant to be installed inside a nix-shell, or is it expected to exist in the user profile? I was under the the impression that I would bring in stack inside the shell via shell.nix then run stack while inside the shell.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai in my case `stack` already exist in my user profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you set up your project, but probably the easiest (but limited) way is to use stack's [nix integration](http://stack.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.10.1/nix_integration.html) which will use GHC and native dependencies from `nix`.

Unfortunately, the stack nix integration is rather backwards. It doesn't use nix to build your package, just to create an environment with GHC and native dependencies. You have to use stack itself to build the project, and since stack will run cabal, it should still work with the flag. The stack nix integration will not generate a .nix file with the dependencies resolved by stack, so you can't build your project with `nix-build` and there's no point in entering `nix-shell`. You would have to use a tool like `stack2nix` or `stackage2nix` for that.

So: build with `stack --nix build` and stack should use nix to set up GHC and native dependencies.

When you're ready for serious business (like automated build and deploy), look into `stack2nix` or `stackage2nix`, use them to freeze the dependencies into a `nix` file, then build and deploy with `nix-build`, `nix-copy-closure` etc.